# MPAndroidChart create new charts with button click

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, onclick, android-espresso

Is it possible to override a chart with another or create a new one under the first with a radio button click or any other button click? I would need 3 bar charts either all of them under each other or one chart that can be refreshed with new data by a button click or radio button click.

```
https://pastebin.com/b1D5aAPr
```

This is how I was thinking.

```
package com.example.zozo07.mobile;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

import com.concretepage.android.R;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ChartActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private BarChart barChart;
    private RadioButton rbA, rbC, rbD;

    private BarDataSet barDataSet;
    private ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries;
    private ArrayList<String> theTitles;
    private BarData theData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chart);

        barChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.bargraph);
        rbA = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbA);
        rbC = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbC);
        rbD = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbD);
        Button btnCreate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreate);

        btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                createBarGraph(new BarEntry(50f, 0), new BarEntry(100f, 1), new BarEntry(20f, 2), barEntries, theTitles, barDataSet, theData);
            }
        });

        registerButtons();

    }

    private void createBarGraph(BarEntry e, BarEntry e2, BarEntry e3, ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries, ArrayList<String> theTitles, BarDataSet barDataSet, BarData theData) {
        barEntries = new ArrayList<>();
        barEntries.add(e);
        barEntries.add(e2);
        barEntries.add(e3);

        barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries, "Data");

        theTitles = new ArrayList<>();
        theTitles.add("Alarm");
        theTitles.add("Sleep");
        theTitles.add("Vacation");


        theData = new BarData(theTitles, barDataSet);
        barChart.setData(theData);

        barChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
        barChart.setDragEnabled(true);
        barChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
    }

    public void registerButtons() {
        register(R.id.rbA);
        register(R.id.rbC);
        register(R.id.rbD);
    }

    private void register(int buttonResourceId){
        findViewById(buttonResourceId).setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
    }

    private OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.rbA:
                    killBarChart();
                    barA();
                    break;
                case R.id.rbC:
                    killBarChart();
                    barB();
                    break;
                case R.id.rbD:
                    killBarChart();
                    barD();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    private void barD() {
        createBarGraph(new BarEntry(30f, 0), new BarEntry(60f, 1), new BarEntry(100f, 2), barEntries, theTitles, barDataSet, theData);
    }

    private void barB() {
        createBarGraph(new BarEntry(20f, 0), new BarEntry(50f, 1), new BarEntry(90f, 2), barEntries, theTitles, barDataSet, theData);
    }

    private void barA() {
        createBarGraph(new BarEntry(80f, 0), new BarEntry(70f, 1), new BarEntry(20f, 2), barEntries, theTitles, barDataSet, theData);
    }

    protected void killBarChart() {
        barEntries = null;
        barDataSet = null;
        theTitles = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and edit your question to show how you've tried to solve the problem already.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible once you change your dataset you can override it easily. Make a method in which you create chart and upon button click or radio selection call that method and pass new values to that it will update your chart.

Answer (score 0):

It's working. I changed my USB cable to another and now my android device is recognized by ADB, so there is no need for an emulator and by tapping on the charts, they change.